# .NET Graph SDK Count Sharepoint Online List Items

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to get a count of list items in a Sharepoint Online list but Graph throw an exception with the following message "invalidRequest - $count is not supported on this API. Only URLs returned by the API can be used to page."

It's not possible to do this operation with a sharepoint list?

```
public async Task<int> GetListItemsCountAsync(string siteId, string listId, List<QueryOption> queryOptions)     
{
    queryOptions ??= new List<QueryOption>();

    var countQueryOption = new QueryOption("count", "true");
    queryOptions.Add(countQueryOption);

    var listItems = await _graphService.Client
        .Sites[siteId]
        .Lists[listId]
        .Items
        .Request(queryOptions)
        .GetAsync();

    return (listItems?.Count ?? 0);
}
```

Another option could be to get all the elements of the list and use the Count property of the resulting collection. But the performance of this approach seems worse.

Answer (score 1):

At least `$count` and `$filter` (for some properties like `id`) operator doesn't work for `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items`.

As an alternative, you can select only `id` property to be returned. It will reduce the size of the response. Then use count on the resulting collection.

```
public async Task<int> GetListItemsCountAsync(string siteId, string listId, List<QueryOption> queryOptions)     
{
    queryOptions ??= new List<QueryOption>();

    var listItems = await _graphService.Client
        .Sites[siteId]
        .Lists[listId]
        .Items
        .Request(queryOptions)
        .Select("id")
        .GetAsync();

    return (listItems?.Count ?? 0);
}
```

Comment: If the $count operator doesn't work I will follow that solution, use only the ID in the query and get the "count" of the collection.

On the other hand, $filter works fine. I am filtering items from different lists using different criteria smootly.

Comment: @Rubén I know that filtering sharepoint list items by id is not possible but filtering by other properties or fields should work